# Wordpress - taxonomy used on multiple post types - how to get_terms / get_categories for just one?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I have registered taxonomies for multiple post types thinking this was the best way to set the site up rather than have the same taxonomies duplicated.

However, now I have run into an issue where I need to list the used taxonomies for  a post type but its listing taxonomies for all both types.  How can I resolve this issue?  Niether get_categories or get_terms seem to have an option to specify which post type you want to get taxonomies for.

***EDIT***
NOTE: Each post type also has multiple taxonomies

Can anyone help?

```
register_taxonomy( 
        'sectors',
        array('case-study', 'resource'),   //used in multiple post types
        [
            'labels' => [
                'name' => __( 'Sectors' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Sector' ),
            ],
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
        ]
    );

    $sectors = get_categories( array('taxonomy' => 'sectors') );  //prints out selected taxonomies for both case studies and resources when I want just resources.

   $services = get_categories( array('taxonomy' => 'services') );
```

Comment: I think this could help  : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96444/only-list-categories-that-contain-posts-of-a-specific-custom-post-type

Comment: This doesn't work for me, maybe because it has been built with a single category in mind for each post type when mine had multiple categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following code which works like a charm :)

```
function df_terms_clauses( $clauses, $taxonomy, $args ) {
    if ( isset( $args['post_type'] ) && ! empty( $args['post_type'] ) && $args['fields'] !== 'count' ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $post_types = array();

        if ( is_array( $args['post_type'] ) ) {
            foreach ( $args['post_type'] as $cpt ) {
                $post_types[] = "'" . $cpt . "'";
            }
        } else {
            $post_types[] = "'" . $args['post_type'] . "'";
        }

        if ( ! empty( $post_types ) ) {
            $clauses['fields'] = 'DISTINCT ' . str_replace( 'tt.*', 'tt.term_taxonomy_id, tt.taxonomy, tt.description, tt.parent', $clauses['fields'] ) . ', COUNT(p.post_type) AS count';
            $clauses['join'] .= ' LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . ' AS r ON r.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->posts . ' AS p ON p.ID = r.object_id';
            $clauses['where'] .= ' AND (p.post_type IN (' . implode( ',', $post_types ) . ') OR p.post_type IS NULL)';
            $clauses['orderby'] = 'GROUP BY t.term_id ' . $clauses['orderby'];

            //print_r( $clauses );
        } 
    }
    return $clauses;
}

add_filter( 'terms_clauses', 'df_terms_clauses', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: That's the one I use too. Shame get_terms() doesn't have built in support for this.

Comment: Ugh that's a pretty ugly query unusable imo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php

     $custom_terms = get_terms('custom_taxonomy_name');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'custom_post_type_name',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy_name',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';
        endwhile;
     }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$terms = get_terms( 'animal_cat', array(
    'orderby'    => 'count',
    'hide_empty' => 0
) );
foreach( $terms as $term ) {

    // Define the query
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'animal',
        'animal_cat' => $term->slug
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

}
```

Comment: This brings out a load of posts.  Im looking for an array of categories